# A kinetic mouse lag when connecting to a TV via HDMI

Tags: windows-7, mouse, hdmi, lag

I've been unable to find out what is causing a mouse cursor lag when I'm using my Win7 laptop connected to a 1080p TV via HDMI.

The symptom can be described as the cursor feeling 'heavy'. When I'm using the TV screen as an extension to the desktop, there is no lag on the laptop side of the desktop. It does not feel like a refresh rate problem: for example scrolling a big web page on the TV side is pretty OK.

Strange huh? Help appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some TV adds a delay on the display of the images because video processor in the TV can makes some treatment on the incoming video. Try using the "game" mode, this will reduce the delay between when the images are received and when they are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the touch pad or an external mouse?  I would check the mouse settings, there may be an option that relates to the touch pad touch area in relation to the screen.  For example, it can be set to absolute or relative.  That may be a cause when it is switching to the larger screen.  I know that I have something like that when using a pen tablet with my PC running windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a 36" flat panel t.v. as my game monitor using hdmi input.
I never had a lag until I changed my Game setting to OFF and it went away when
I turned the Game mode back on.